# Leaking detected when presenting UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

Here is the code which I use to present a `UIImagePickerController`:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

  if (![UIImagePickerController
          isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
        alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
                         message:NSLocalizedString(@"Device has no camera", nil)
                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok =
        [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

  } else {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
}
```

At the moment I run this method (eg. tap on `UIButton`) I can see this in Instruments:

[image: Leaks By Backtrace]

And this is what I see if I change to Cycles & Roots:

[image: Cycles and Roots]

So if I hover over the first leak, and press an arrow that pops out, I get this:

[image]

and if I open stack trace for this method I see:

[image]

So it is mostly system calls. Same goes for other leak, just system calls... So is this a bug or ?? If I open and dismiss image picker few times I get even more leaks, a lot more...

Anybody have noticed this?

Comment: As I already mentioned in my comment on [bisma's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41957869/3402095), in callback methods I am only having a code that dismisses picker : `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make UIImagePickerController *picker a strong property. So that app has a global reference to that picker and you will be able to dismiss it.

Comment: I am able to dismiss it already, in methods meant for that (see `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol). In docs it is stated that :  "The picker does not dismiss itself; the client dismisses it in these callbacks." I mean I can try what you said, but I am currently using this control as it supposed to be used according to the docs.